# Android volley get callback when all requests finish

Tags: android, networking, future, android-volley

I am using volley to queue a series of requests. I am showing a progress dialog to the user when these requests are happening. Is there a way I can check when all these requests are finished.
This is what I want.

```
//Show progress bar
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    //create request and add the request
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
// When last request finsihes dismiss progres bar
```

Is there a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep the total number of requests in a member variable :

```
int pendingRequests = 0;

//...
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    requestQueue.add(request);
    pendingRequests++;
}
```

Then each time a request finishes you decrement the counter, and if it reaches 0, you know that all requests are done.

Comment: I used an AtomicInteger because there can be concurrency issues.

Comment: Good answer! Spent a while looking for the solution, but this is simple and straightforward.