# Finish activity when a response is returned from the server, but wait for animation to end

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I send a request to server via Volley; And after send, increase a variable that show number of requests.

```
VolleyGeneral.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObj,TAG);
numberOfReq++;
```

Then when I get the response, decrease that variable.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
    numberOfReq--;
}
```

On another side, i'm showing an image, using fade in animation for 2 seconds then I finish the activity and go to the next activity.

But i want to wait for all the server responses before finishing the activity. So i write this part like it:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
    while(numberOfReq == 0){
        numberOfReq = -1;
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        break;
    }
}
```

If server send the responses before 2 second, everything is Okey.

**But** if response is received after 2 second, the activity doesn't finish.

Comment: Isn't there an `onError` or `onTimeout` or a similar callback method in the Volley library?

Comment: @Tim Yes, there is. But why?! I wrote just some part of my code.

Comment: Because after 2 seconds animation already ended and it will no more executing while loop. So code inside not executes.

Comment: You can use timer to execute code after animation end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, because the answer seems incredibly simple. Just set a flag whenever the activity is "ready to finish", and then check for this condition in `onResponse()` too.

Either `onAnimationEnd()` or the last `onResponse()` will run first, and the second one should start the second activity. For example:

```
private boolean mReadyToProceed;

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
{
    if (numberOfReq == 0)
        startOtherActivityAndFinish();
    else
       mReadyToProceed = true;
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
{
    numberOfReq--;
    if (mReadyToProceed && numberOfReq == 0)
        startOtherActivityAndFinish();
}
```

(Note: make sure that the decrement and comparison is not affected by other request threads finishing, possibly with locks or by using `AtomicInteger`).

Answer (score 3):

You are aware of the fact that Volley creates and maintains multiple threads, right?

Increments/decrements are not thread safe operations. Instead use something like:

```
AtomicInteger numberOfReq = new AtomicInteger(0);

numberOfReq.incrementAndGet(); // ++

numberOfReq.decrementAndGet(); // --
```

Not sure this is the cause of your problem, but event if not - it's a bug waiting to happen.

EDIT:

Setting numberOfReq to be a volatile int will not solve the problem.

Volatile does not guarantee atomicity. it only guarantees that the next 
thread to read a variable will see its exact value after operations performed
by a prior thread.

Now, increment (and decrement) operation is in fact a triplet:

```
a = x;
b = a + 1;
x = b;
```

If atomicity is not forced on this calculation, e.g. by using AtomicInteger, 
nothing will stop another thread visiting even a volatile field in the middle of such calculation and basically do away with the increment-in-process.

Comment: I just follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242432/android-volley-get-callback-when-all-requests-finish

I'm not sure but i think you are right. I'm not sure because i don't write application in multi threading mode. And the other reason is so what is usage of volatile keyword?

Answer (score 0):

As matiash answered you can use set a flag on the onResponse() and can check that value to get the desired result or you can use the broadcast recievers that can be an effective solution also

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the check two way instead of one i.e

If the response arrives whilst you're animating then your **onAnimationEnd()** must be responsible for shutting down and starting the new activity

Else the otherway round(the image animation ends before the response) **onResponse()** must be responsible for performing activity finish and new activity.

Ps: Regarding thread safe variables @matiash seems to have thrown enough light

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the method where you start the other activity. Something like this:

```
private boolean animationEnded = false;    

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
    numberOfReq--;
    checkStartOtherActivity();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
    animationEnded = true;
    checkStartOtherActivity();
}

public void checkStartOtherActivity(){
    if (numberOfReq == 0 && animationEnded){
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
    }
}
```